# How to check if username is already exists in data table with LINQ TO SQL

Tags: c#, sql, database, linq, visual-studio

im using visual studio c#;

```
var d = new linqclassDataContext();
var c = new Table();
            c.Id =System.Convert.ToInt32(confirmationCode);
            c.username = txtUserName.Text;
            c.password = txtPaswword.Text;
            c.mail = txtMail.Text;
            d.Tables.InsertOnSubmit(c);
            d.SubmitChanges();
```

I want to check if username is already in DT
 PLEASE HELP...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to do.  You can use `Any` as shown below:

```
if (!d.Tables.Any(t => t.username.Equals(txtUserName.Text)))
{
   d.Tables.InsertOnSubmit(c);
   d.SubmitChanges();
}
```

Note: This doesn't consider case.  You may consider using `ToLower()` or `ToUpper()` if needed.